# How do I allow users to only delete branches that they created

Tags: azure-devops

How can I restrict branch deletion to only branches created by the user?

I'm having trouble finding a setting that allows users to only delete the branches they created. Currently, I can only allow a user to delete all branches or no branches. Is there a setting I'm missing or a workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need [Force push permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops) to be able to delete branches. It is set on the repository level and doesn't distinguish per branch. So you gain all or nothing with this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Force push is needed to delete branches, and it CAN be defined at branch level - but only after the branch is created.
This should be a default IMHO that creator of a branch should be able to delete it.

Comment: That contradicts the previous answer. Is this something you've read or is it something you've seen in action. (I don't want a user to accidentaly delete some branch created by someone else.)

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy It is something I've used on several branches.